# Finding words in tree by prefix

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-search-tree, prefix

In my binary search tree I want to create a function that can get all words starting with a prefix and store all words in an array called results 
this is my tree

```
struct BinarySearchTree_t
{
    char *mot,*def;
    struct BinarySearchTree_t *left;
    struct BinarySearchTree_t *right;
};
typedef struct BinarySearchTree_t BinarySearchTree;
```

my function :

```
size_t findWordsByPrefix(BinarySearchTree* tree, char* prefix, char*** results)
{
    BinarySearchTree *tmp;
        tmp=tree;

    static int size=0;

    if (!tmp)
        return 0;
    else if (strncmp(tmp->mot,prefix,strlen(prefix))==0)
    {

        (*results)= realloc(*results,(1+size)*sizeof(*(*results)));
        (*(*results+size))= malloc(strlen(tmp->mot)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy((*results)[size],tmp->mot);
        size++;
       return (1 + findWordsByPrefix(tmp->left,prefix, &results) + findWordsByPrefix(tmp->right,prefix, &results));
    }
    else
        return (strncmp(tmp->mot,prefix,strlen(prefix))<0)?findWordsByPrefix(tmp->right,prefix, &results):findWordsByPrefix(tmp->left,prefix, &results) ;
}
```

This function should return a number of words starting with the given prefix.
my problem is that the program crash when it is run , and I don't how to resize my array results 
so every time I found a word I should increase the size of the results array .

and I would know how exacly manipulate the pointer of pointer of pointer given in arg of this function (`char ***results`) : what exactly means?

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a linked list for results? Then you can either copy the string to a malloc'ed buffer or, depending on your data, just copy a pointer to it. If it must be a separate array, copy the linked list values to the array after the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I simply compile your code, I get severe compiler warnings including:

```
1>binarysearchtree.c(98) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char ***' differs in levels of indirection from 'char ****'
1>binarysearchtree.c(98) : warning C4024: 'findWordsByPrefix' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
```

This alone will cause a crash -- you are calling your own function recursively with the wrong arguments.

Next, I believe you need to allocate one more than the length of the string, to hold a copy of a string:

```
malloc((strlen(tmp->mot) + 1 )*sizeof(char))
```

Next, you're passing around an array of strings of variable size -- and storing the size in a static variable.  It's impossible to know if this will work, so don't do it.

Instead, if you want to use a dynamic array of strings, I suggest extracting out a struct to hold them, like so:

```
struct ResultTable_t
{
    int    size;
    char **results;
};

typedef struct ResultTable_t ResultTable;

void InitializeResults(ResultTable *p_table)
{
    p_table->size = 0;
    p_table->results = NULL;
}

void AddResult(ResultTable *p_table, char *result)
{
    if (result == NULL)
        return;
    p_table->size++;
    p_table->results = realloc(p_table->results, p_table->size * sizeof(*p_table->results));
    p_table->results[p_table->size-1] = malloc((strlen(result) + 1) * sizeof(**p_table->results));
    strcpy(p_table->results[p_table->size-1], result);
}

void FreeResults(ResultTable *p_table)
{
    if (p_table->results != NULL)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < p_table->size; i++)
        {
            free(p_table->results[i]);
        }
        free(p_table->results);
    }
    p_table->size = 0;
    p_table->results = NULL;
}
```

(As an improvement, you might consider using [geometric growth instead of linear growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) for your table of results.)

Then your function becomes:

```
size_t findWordsByPrefix(BinarySearchTree* tree, char* prefix, ResultTable *p_table)
{
    if (!tree)
        return 0;
    else if (strncmp(tree->mot,prefix,strlen(prefix))==0)
    {
        AddResult(p_table, tree->mot);
        return (1 + findWordsByPrefix(tree->left,prefix, p_table) + findWordsByPrefix(tree->right,prefix, p_table));
    }
    else if (strncmp(tree->mot,prefix,strlen(prefix))<0)
    {
        return findWordsByPrefix(tree->right,prefix, p_table);
    }
    else
    {
        return findWordsByPrefix(tree->left,prefix, p_table);
    }
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
ResultTable results;

InitializeResults(&results);

// Get some prefix to search for.
char prefix = GetSomePrefix();

int size = findWordsByPrefix(tree, prefix, &results);

// Do something with the results

// Free all memory of the results

FreeResults(&results);
```

**Update**

If the `ResultTable` is distasteful for some reason, you can pass the dynamic array and array sizes in directly:

```
void AddResult(char ***p_results, int *p_size, char *word) 
{ 
    if (word == NULL) 
        return; 
    (*p_size)++; 
    (*p_results) = realloc(*p_results, ((*p_size)+1) * sizeof(**p_results)); 
    (*p_results)[(*p_size)-1] = malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(***p_results)); 
    strcpy((*p_results)[(*p_size)-1], word);
}

void FreeResults(char ***p_results, int *p_size)
{
    int i;

    if (p_results == NULL || *p_results == NULL)
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < (*p_size); i++)
    {
        free ((*p_results)[i]);
    }
    free (*p_results);

    *p_results = NULL;
    *p_size = 0;
}

size_t findWordsByPrefix(BinarySearchTree* tree, char* prefix, char ***p_results, int *p_size)
{
    if (!tree)
        return 0;
    else if (strncmp(tree->mot,prefix,strlen(prefix))==0)
    {
        AddResult(p_results, p_size, tree->mot);
        return (1 + findWordsByPrefix(tree->left,prefix, p_results, p_size) + findWordsByPrefix(tree->right,prefix, p_results, p_size));
    }
    else if (strncmp(tree->mot,prefix,strlen(prefix))<0)
    {
        return findWordsByPrefix(tree->right,prefix, p_results, p_size);
    }
    else
    {
        return findWordsByPrefix(tree->left,prefix, p_results, p_size);
    }
}
```

and use like:

```
char **results = NULL;
int    tablesize = 0;

// Get some prefix to search for.
char prefix = GetSomePrefix();

int size = findWordsByPrefix(tree, prefix, &results, &tablesize);

// Do something with the results

// Free all memory of the results

FreeResults(&results, &tablesize);
```

Comment: can I use the function add results with array not a struct ?
like that : 

void AddResult(char ***results, char *word)
{
    static size_t size=0;
    if (word == NULL)
        return;
    size++;
    (*results) = realloc(*results, (size+1) * sizeof(**results));
    (*results)[size-1] = malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(***results));
    strcpy((*results)[size-1], word);
}

and i called it like this :
AddResult(results, word);

but it still crash

Comment: @user3148218 - if you use a static variable to remember the array size of the array being passed in, it's *impossible to determine the correctness of your code without reading all of it*.  There is no way from by looking at the subroutines to determine whether the argument and static variable are in sync.  For instance, if you call `findWordsByPrefix` twice to collect a different set of results, it will crash.  Instead, the array and array size should be kept together.